# Two errors using class and header

Tags: c++

I get the error class redefinition

Also the error ID is not a member of class process

and missing semi colon before ID

I tried char* instead of string.. not working also

Any help?  I seem to be missing something

Thanks in advance

process.h file

```
#ifndef PROCESS_H
#define PROCESS_H


 class process
{
public:

 string ID;
 int run_time;
 int arrival_time;

 process();

 int get_start_time();
 int get_finish_time(int start, int run);
 int get_TA_time(int finish, int start);
 float get_weighted_TA_time();

};

#endif
```

process.cpp file

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include "process.h"

using namespace std;

class process
{ 
public:

 process:: process() {};
 int process:: get_start_time()
 {
     int x;
     return x;
 }
 int process:: get_finish_time(int start, int run)
 {
     int x;
     return x= start +run;
 }
 int process:: get_TA_time(int finish, int start)
 {
     int x;
     return x= finish - start;
 }
 float process::  get_weighted_TA_time()
 {};
 };
```

Comment: As you are defining class in both file so its giving `class redefinition` error. Second add `"string.h"` into header file.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem 1** Class refinition
In `cpp` file you don't need to write `class process`. It should be

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#include "process.h"

using namespace std;

process:: process() {};
int process:: get_start_time()
{
    int x;
    return x;
}
int process:: get_finish_time(int start, int run)
{
    int x;
    return x= start +run;
}
int process:: get_TA_time(int finish, int start)
{
    int x;
    return x= finish - start;
}
float process::  get_weighted_TA_time()
{};
```

In header file you have given required declarations. In `cpp`, you need to give the definitions. But because you are outside the class scope now, you must give the fully qualified name of members which you are already doing. (for ex: int `process::` get_finish_time(int start, int run))

If you again use `class process`, compiler has no hint that you intend the same class and not want a new class causing the class redifinition error. In C++, it is not allowed to make a class partially and complete the rest of it somewhere else. (Not to be cofused with inheritance)

**Problem 2**: string issue
Add `#include <string>` in your header file and use `std::string` or add line `using std::string`

Comment: THANKS, That corrected the class redefinition error!!

Comment: Any idea on how to fix the string ID problem too?

Comment: @MaramAlaa Include "STRING.H" in YOUR header file

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues.  One is this:

`process.h` needs to `#include <string>`.  Once included, prepend all string variables with `std::`.

```
    #ifndef PROCESS_H
    #define PROCESS_H

    #include <string>
    class process
    {
        public:
           std::string ID;
           int run_time;
           int arrival_time;

           process();
           int get_start_time();
           int get_finish_time(int start, int run);
           int get_TA_time(int finish, int start);
           float get_weighted_TA_time();
   };
   #endif
```

The problem with your original code is that you're:

1. Relying that some outside module included `<string>` before `process.h` is included.
2. Relying that some outside module stated `using namespace std;` before including `process.h`.

None of those can be guaranteed.